# How did they know what an Omega looks like?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

In the film *Edge of Tomorrow*, when Rita takes Cage to see the scientist, they are shown a picture of an Omega. But, they don't know where the Omega is, and they never say it's ever been in a known position and then moved. So, how do they know in such detail what it looks like? How would anyone ever have seen it?

Comment: I assumed that intel came from Rita's dreams.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the same scene where the Omega is first mentioned -- and shown via a holographic 3D image -- it was explained that Rita had seen the Omega in visions, and that Cage would experience similar visions himself.

> Dr. Carter: Visions! Have you seen any visions like that?
>
> [pointing to the 3D image of the Omega]
>
> Dr. Carter: The Omega senses when it’s losing control of its power, even now it's mentally searching to find you.
>
> Rita: When it’s close to finding you, you will start having visions. You’ll start to see that.
>
> [points to the 3D image of the Omega]
>
> Dr. Carter: You’ll even see where it is.
>
> Cage: And you had these visions?
>
> Rita: Yes.
>
> Cage: But eventually you saw it. I mean, you actually saw it. Right?
>
> [Rita hesitates a moment before replying]
>
> Rita: Never in the flesh.
>
> Cage: So this is all just some… theory. You don’t know if this thing even exists.
>
> Rita: **The visions showed me it was at Verdun, I could see it! I… I just… lost the power before I could get to it.**

> Cage did later see the Omega in a vision. He subsequently discovered that the vision was a ruse intended to lure him into a trap, and that the Omega was not in the location the vision showed it to be in. However, the vision did show him what the Omega looked like, and the same was presumably true for Rita.